# load recordset into array in php

Tags: php, recordset

It loops through and I see it going through all the data correctly, but when I try to assign it to an array using $i - it just keeps replacing it, it doesn't add a new value to the array.

Thanks in advance!!

```
$index = "";

$service_singular = "";

$service_plural= "";

$sub_service = "";

$description = "";

$duration = "";

$duration_descript = "";

$price = "";

$i = 0;

if ($fac_id != "" && $fac_id != 0){
if ($stmt = $mysqli->prepare("SELECT `index`,`service_singular`, `service_plural`, `sub_service`, `description`, `duration`, `duration_descript`, `price` FROM `service` WHERE `fac_id`= ?")) {

$stmt->bind_param('s', $fac_id); // Bind "fac_id" to parameter.

$stmt->execute(); // Execute the prepared query.

$stmt->store_result();

// $i = $stmt->num_rows;

$stmt->bind_result($index,$service_singular, $service_plural, $sub_service, $description, $duration, $duration_descript, $price); // get variables from result.

while ($stmt->fetch()){

enter code here
     $i = $i++; }


}
```

Comment: $i = $i++ makes no sense. Either do just $i++; or do $i += 1;

Comment: And bind_param should take 'i' instead of 's' where I assume fac_id is an integer id

Answer (score 0):

You aren't doing anything with an array:

```
while ($stmt->fetch()){
     $rows[] = array($index, $service_singular, $service_plural, $sub_service,
                     $description, $duration, $duration_descript, $price);
}
```

Though I would just use results http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-result.fetch-all.php.

Comment: Thanks so much - this worked.  I was originally setting $i to zero and incrementing it and putting it in the [] section like [$i] and it just kept one occurrence and changed the number.  I also tried to initialize it before the loop with the number of rows to set the size, but that didn't work either.  I'm new to PHP - thanks